# Change the language of application using ResourceBundle

Tags: java, internationalization, resourcebundle, i18n-gem

I'm building a internationalized application based of Java using Netbeans IDE, I´m trying to change the language of my frames using a combobox located in a singular frame, but I cant make the code for do that, can any help me?

The combobox contains a some Objects with a Local value identifier. I want to take this value and change the Locale of the frames, then change the languages of the Frames.

I tried to change the base Local, but that does not work. What do I do?

Comment: By 'Frames' DYM 'JFrames' or (java.awt.)'Frames'?   By 'Local' DYM 'Locale'?  Please try to be specific and exact.  It is hard enough debugging problems on international forums without the questions being sloppy in use of terminology.

Comment: @Andrew: He said Netbeans IDE. This is the lame way to build Swing application. Thus JFrame he meant (Yoda rulez).

Comment: @Edgar: Fortunately Netbeans IDE follows best practices and would not let you easily implement language switching anti-pattern. Instead it will automatically detect valid locale (that user already chosen for his/her UI) and display translations using this locale (provided that you have corresponding .properties file). If you want to bypass this mechanism, you would need to create all your UI by hand (or thoroughly modify generated classes).

Comment: @PawełDyda, I used Netbeans for internationalize my application, all ok, but I trying to change the lenguaje of a open JFrame using a JComboBox with Locale Objects, when the user change the selection, the next JDialogs or JFrame change the locale, but the form with contains the JCombobox don't change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to making your application i18n ready. Then you need to use resource bundles for localization. Read this [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/resbundle/index.html) end to end.

Comment: I'm using the internationalizing wizard of Netbeans.